# What exactly are protocols and delegates and how are they used in IOS?

Tags: ios, delegates, protocols

I'm really confused about the concept of delegates and protocols. Are they equivalent of interfaces and adapter classes in Java? How do they work? 
None of the resources I've read were helpful so far. 
"Delegation is a simple and powerful pattern in which one object in a program acts on behalf of, or in coordination with, another object. The delegating object keeps a reference to the other object—the delegate—and at the appropriate time sends a message to it." I have no idea what this means. 
Can someone please explain what they are and give a simple example? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

As far as I now understand,

1) delegates implement protocols (another name for interfaces)

2) object registers a delegate (that implements a protocol)

3) object can call protocol methods on the delegate

Therefore, a delegate is connecting the object with the protocol.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

I still don't understand why the object itself can't implement a protocol? It could've been so much easier!

Comment: which articles have you read and which examples did you find that you couldnt figure out?

Comment: No, delegates are not like interfaces.

Comment: Protocols are like interfaces in Java. They are a concrete feature of the Objective-C language. Delegates, however, are objects which are connected to other objects and are sent messages when the state of that "other object" changes. They are just a *pattern.*

Comment: Totumus Maximus: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html

http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html

Couldn't figure out what delegates are and what protocols are. If you take time to answer a question, at least use that time wisely and actually answer a question, instead of asking another.

Comment: Matt Ball, thank you so much for this sophisticated and thoughtful answer. 

H2CO3, hi! I'm glad to see the first nice person here!
I don't understand this: "objects which are connected to other objects and are sent messages when the state of that "other object" changes". So, when that "other object" is changed, it sends a message to a delegate? Why? Could you give a simple example please?

Comment: The two sentences you quote are a pretty good summary. What do you find confusing about them?

Comment: ole_92. An object declares a protocol when it cannot do a job just by itself or just wants to allow other parties to participate in the event. For example a UITableView couldn't be the flexible class it is, if it didn't ask it's dataSource or delegate to provide some information or respond to some user interactions.

Comment: Exactly!  Imagine what a pain it would be if you had to subclass UITableView every time you wanted to change its contents.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Protocols are a way to specify a set of methods you want a class to implement if it wants to work with one of your classes. Delegates and Data Sources like UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource are protocols indeed.

You specify a protocol this way:

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)aRequiredMethod;

@required
- (void)anotherRequiredMethod;

@optional
- (void)anOptionalMethod;

@end
```

Methods declared after the @required or before any other specifier are required and the classes that want to use your protocol need to implement all of them. You can also declare some optional methods by declaring them after the @optional specifier.

You then can specify that a class "conforms" to a protocol (implements the required methods) in the interface of the class:

```
@interface MyClass <MyProtocol>

@end
```

You usually keep a reference to an object conforming to a protocol using a property. For example, to keep track of a delegate:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MyProtocol> delegate;
```

At this point, in your code, you just have to call the method you want to call on the object that you're keeping reference of and that implements your protocol as you would with any other method:

```
[self.delegate aRequiredMethod];
```

To check whether an object conforms to a protocol you can call

```
[self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)]
```

To check whether an object implements a method you can call

```
[self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(anOptionalMethod)]
```

For more information, check the Apple's guide [Working With Protocols](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer!

So, regarding this sentence: "Delegates and Data Sources like UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource are protocols indeed."
Delegates are a type of protocols?

"You usually keep reference to an object conforming to a protocol using a property. For example, to keep track of a delegate:"
So, delegate is a reference to an object that implements the protocol?

Comment: You're welcome. Delegates are not really a type of protocols. They're called like that because they usually ask for information required to for fulfilling a task. E.g. the UITableViewDataSource asks for all the information a UITableView needs to display your data (numberOfCells, numberOfSections, etc.). A delegate protocol, instead, it's called like that because it usually acts in response of an action that it's delegated to them. The UITableViewDelegate for example delegates the events like the user tapping a cell to the viewController this way.

Comment: I had no space left for this in the previous comment… but… yes, I used 'delegate' to mean an object that implemented the protocol.

Answer (score 10):

A protocol which declared with the `(@protocol syntax in Objective-C)` is used the declare a set of methods that a class that "adopts" (declares that it will use this protocol) will implement. This means that you can specify in your code that, "you don't care which class is used so long as it implements a particular protocol". This can be done in Objective-C as follows:

```
id<MyProtocol> instanceOfClassThatImplementsMyProtocol;
```

If you state this in your code, then any class that "conforms" to the protocol MyProtocol can be used in the variable `instanceOfClassThatImplementsMyProtocol`. This means that the code that uses this variable knows that it can use whichever methods are defined in MyProtocol with this particular variable, regardless of what class it is. This is a great way of avoiding the inheritance design pattern, and avoids tight coupling.

Delegates are a use of the language feature of protocols. The delegation design pattern is a way of designing your code to use protocols where necessary. In the Cocoa frameworks, the delegate design pattern is used to specify an instance of a class which conforms to a particular protocol. This particular protocol specifies methods that the delegate class should implement to perform specific actions at given events. The class that uses the delegate knows that its delegate coforms to the protocol, so it knows that it can call the implemented methods at given times. This design pattern is a great way of decoupling the classes, because it makes it really easy to exchange one delegate instance for another - all the programmer has to do is ensure that the replacement instance or class conforms to the necessary protocol (i.e. it implements the methods specified in the protocol)!

Protocols and delegates are not restricted only to Objective-C and Mac/iOS development, but the Objective-C language and the Apple frameworks make heavy use of this awesome language feature and design pattern.

Edit:

Please find this Example. In the `UIKit framework` of Cocoa Touch, there is a `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol. This protocol defines a series of methods that classes which are delegates of a `UITextField` instance should implement. In other words, if you want to assign a delegate to a `UITextField` (using the delegate property), you'd better make sure that this class conforms to `UITextFieldDelegate`. In fact, because the delegate property of `UITextField` is defined as:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UITextFieldDelegate> delegate
```

Then, the compiler will give warnings if you assign a class to it that doesn't implement the protocol. This is really useful. You have to state that a class implements a protocol, and in saying that it does, you're letting other classes know that they can interact in a particular way with your class. So, if you assign an instance of `MyTextFieldDelegateClass` to the delegate property of `UITextField`, the `UITextField` knows that it can call some particular methods (related to text entry, selection etc.) of your `MyTextFieldDelegateClass`. It knows this because `MyTextFieldDelegateClass` has said that it will implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol.

Ultimately, this all leads to much greater flexibility and adaptability in your project's code, which I'm sure you'll soon realise after using this technology! :)

Answer (score 9):

In it's simplest form a delegate is an object which receives messages from another object.  And you do it all the time.

So say you had car object with an engine.

```
@interface car : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) id engine;

@end
```

So could forward a start message to the engine.

```
[_engine start];
```

The engine is acting as a delegate, you're just passing it a message.

Protocols make it more formal, and Xcode will check that you are conforming to the required or optional methods.

```
@property (nonatomic) id <engineDelegate> engine;
```

says that the engine object MUST contain the function start because in the the protocol definition it asked for it.

```
@protocol engineDelegate 
 - (void) start;
@optional
 - (double) fuelLevel;
@end
```

Why are delegates and protocols so cool?  Well because the engine could be any number of different engines which you could use at runtime, it could be a jet engine, a combustion engine, a phasing modulating engine it doesn't matter, as long as it conforms to the protocol.  And you tell Xcode that it does conform by adding the delegate to the class interface.

```
@interface timeWarpDrive : NSObject <engineDelegate>
```

Comment: This answer would be more helpful for beginners if you elaborate on your code examples by showing the filenames/full code examples for each file.