# Selecting the text in the tableview cell and returning to previous view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm quite new to this site and iOS development. I have an app that I'm working on, in it, I'm working on a view where when the users taps one button named "zones" the view calls a table view with a list of zones. I'm currently able to make a selection. But what I want is to return back to the previous view when user makes a selection on that table and I want to copy that text in the selection to a variable. Tried so many things. Nothing came close :(

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
[super viewDidLoad];


 zones=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"392A", @"382F", @"388A", @"373A", @"372A", @"373B", @"366A", @"367A", @"368B", @"362A", @"364A", @"356A",@"357A", @"364B", @"354A",@"353A", @"342A", nil];
NSLog(@"Apple");
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell           forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
cell.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home.png"]];
}

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
return [zones count];
}




-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
static NSString *tableIdentifier = @"zonesTable";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableIdentifier];



if (cell==nil)
{
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyleDefault) reuseIdentifier:tableIdentifier];

}

cell.textLabel.text = [zones objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;

}

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

 {

UITableViewCell *cellValue = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

NSLog(@"%@", cellValue); //Not Even getting the NSLog output in Xcode ;(


  }
```

Comment: You need to post code which you have attempted. Such as, the variable which will hold the text, and the tableview code.

Comment: I think you need to use protocols. Have a look at this link ---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192287/what-exactly-are-protocols-and-delegates-and-how-are-they-used-in-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    self.currentCityName = [[self.cityArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] cityName];
    [self.cityTableView reloadData];
    [self.delegate cityDidGetSelected:[self.cityArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    //putting 1/3 of delay
    [self performSelector:@selector(cancelButtonPressed) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
}
```

CancelButtonPressed Method:

```
-(void) cancelButtonPressed {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I have been using a delegate method `cityDidGetSelected`. Implement it in your view controller and pass the zone or city name to it.

CancelButtonPressed will work if you are using `presentViewController` to show your `tableView`.