# Delegate use with CLLocationManagerDelegate not working objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, ibeacon

I have create a custom delegate with CLLocationManagerDelegate when i call the delegate methods inside CLLocationManagerDelegate delegates are not working properly. i think the way i create the delegate was wrong can someone tell me what i have done wrong ?

`.h file`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol iBeaconDeligate<NSObject>
@required
-(void)getArray:(NSArray *)beaconArray;
@end

@interface iBeaconDeligate : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property CLProximity lastProximity;

-(void) initiBeaconDeligate;

@end
```

this is `.m file`

```
#import "iBeaconDeligate.h"

@implementation iBeaconDeligate


-(void) initiBeaconDeligate
{

    NSUUID *beaconUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:
                          @"XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"];
    NSString *beaconIdentifier = @"iBeaconModules.us";
    CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:
                                    beaconUUID identifier:beaconIdentifier];

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    //[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    //[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    // New iOS 8 request for Always Authorization, required for iBeacons to work!
    if([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;

    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion];
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void)sendLocalNotificationWithMessage:(NSString*)message {

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60];
    notification.alertBody = message;
    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:
(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
    NSString *message = @"";

    if(beacons.count > 0) {
        CLBeacon *nearestBeacon = beacons.firstObject;



        if(nearestBeacon.proximity == self.lastProximity ||
           nearestBeacon.proximity == CLProximityUnknown) {
            return;
        }

        self.lastProximity = nearestBeacon.proximity;



        switch(nearestBeacon.proximity) {
            case CLProximityFar:
                message = @"You are far away from the beacon";
                break;
            case CLProximityNear:
                message = @"You are near the beacon";
                break;
            case CLProximityImmediate:
                message = @"You are in the immediate proximity of the beacon";
                break;
            case CLProximityUnknown:
                return;
        }
    } else {
        message = @"No beacons are nearby";
    }


    [self performSelector:@selector(getArray:) withObject:beacons];
    NSLog(@"%@", message);
    [self sendLocalNotificationWithMessage:message];


}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    [manager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    NSLog(@"You entered the region.");
    [self sendLocalNotificationWithMessage:@"You entered the region."];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
         didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    [manager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region];
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    NSLog(@"You exited the region.");
    [self sendLocalNotificationWithMessage:@"You exited the region."];
}

@end
```

this is how i called it in my controller class

.h
`@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController<iBeaconDeligate>`

.m

```
iBeaconDeligate *sampleProtocol = [[iBeaconDeligate alloc]init];

[sampleProtocol initiBeaconDeligate];
```

the problem was  methodes that invoke automatically in `CLLocationManagerDelegate` are not calling in my custom delegate

Comment: The @protocol definition doesn't make sense - You just seem to be defining a class.  I suspect your problem is that `sampleProtocol` is a local variable, so as soon as that method exits the object ceases to exist

Comment: @Paulw11 thank for the advice and making sampleProtocal global solve everything. if  you make this comment as a answer i can up vote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `sampleProtocol` is a local variable inside the method, it will be deallocated when the method exits.

You should create a `(strong) @property` to store this object to ensure it is retained.

Comment: but one small problem though when `[self performSelector:@selector(getArray:) withObject:beacons];` was called is gives me `NSInvalidArgumentException` any idea why this happening ?

Comment: because your class doesn't implement the `getArray` method.  As I said, I don't know what you are trying to achieve with the @protocol but your code doesn't implement a delegate pattern

Comment: when the beacon detected i want to get it to my view controller thats why i wrote `getArray` how can i archive this ?

Comment: You should implement a proper delegate pattern.  Your `iBeacondeligate` class will have a `delegate` property.  Your hosting class will be assigned to that property `self.sampleProtocol.delegate=self` and implement the protocol. Then you can invoke the delegate method `[self.delegate didDiscoverBeacons:beacons]`.  It is best practice to check that the delegate `respondsToSelector` before invoking the method

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192287/what-exactly-are-protocols-and-delegates-and-how-are-they-used-in-ios and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html