# how to Pass recordedFile to collection view cell either by block completion or notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, avcapturesession

Hi I have an video recored output and i want to parse it to the other controller using either blocks or nsnotification center. Here is the code used to get output.

```
- (void)saveRecordedFile:(NSURL *)recordedFile {

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [assetLibrary writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:recordedFile
                                         completionBlock:
         ^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {

             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{



                 NSString *title;
                 NSString *message;

                 if (error != nil) {

                     title = @"Failed to save video";
                     message = [error localizedDescription];
                 }
                 else {
                     title = @"Saved!";
                     message = nil;
                 }

                 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                                 message:message
                                                                delegate:nil
                                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
                 [alert show];

                 NSLog(@"%@",recordedFile);'
//  
}
```

This output i have to pass to next view controller and from this to time line same like instagram app.

one more thing is already collection view is having images

`some body please  help me to solve this problem`

Comment: can you use protocol and delegate function to achieve this

Comment: @hari i dont know how to use protocol

Comment: @ajay can help me out

Comment: Yes, It is simple concept. I think this link will you to understand it better. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17192587/3077339

Comment: ok @satheesh can you share the value one view controller to another right. first and second viewcontroller are sequence of viewcontroller or more than two viewcontroller to pass the value

Comment: @ajay i want to know how to use protocols to my requirement

Comment: @hari recored out to shareviewcontroller and  back to the tabbed firest view controller